# Chrome extensions : impossible to insert HTML in DOM, permissions problems

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I've a problem with permissions, I want to inject my javascript into a page served from https, http and file

Below the **manifest** file

```
{

    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions":["tabs"],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icone.png",
        "default_title": "displayer."
    },

    "icons" : {
        "128" : "img/icone_128.png",
        "48" : "img/icone_48.png",
        "32" : "img/icone_32.png",
        "24" : "img/icone_24.png",
        "16" : "img/icone_16.png"
    },

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "displayer.",
    "description": "This extension helps you to compare your wireframe with your current coded page..",
    "version": "1.0.1"

 }
```

And the injected javascript **(background.js)**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON
    if (tab.url.indexOf("http://*/*, https://*/*, file://*/*") != -1) { // Inspect whether the place where user clicked matches with our list of URL
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,
        {"file": "contentscript.js"},
        function () { // Execute your code
            console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
        });
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {file: "grid.css"});
    }
});
```

I already tried to "permissions" :["https://*/*, http://*/*, file://*/*"], but it doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow's accepted format, and will probably be closed. Also, it doesn't show what you have already tried, if any, to implement the extension. Do try first, and then come back with concrete, isolated implementation questions.

Comment: Please don't add your life story to your questions

Comment: I highly recommend that you start with [this Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) in the docs. It explains the basics of architecture that you don't "understand between".

Comment: And as for Stack Overflow's accepted format, I see you're relatively new, so have a look at [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: oh okay guys, sorry about that. I'll come back later so.

Comment: `indexOf` searches for a substring. Try `tab.url.indexOf('http:') == 0 || etc..` instead of `.indexOf('http://*/*')`

Comment: I see you have massively edited your question. It's alright, but I must warn you not to do that again, now that there are relevant answers. If you still have another problem - make a new question. Just a friendly heads-up.

Comment: Side note: `chrome.tabs.insertCSS` should also take `tab.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to provide all the permissions is to include, literally, `"<all_urls>"` into the permissions set.

In general, read the [match pattern documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

---

Your other problem is pointed out by Rob W in the comments: `indexOf('http://*/*')` searches for *literally that string*, with asterisks.

You can do, as he recommended, `tab.url.indexOf('http:') == 0` and so on.

Comment: I also tried it but it doesn't change anything, I am currently using "activeTab" for. But thank you to your answer.

Comment: @kitkatball Added your other problem to the answer.